# how do you add footer? like all right's reserved for a CSS design?

Tags: css

i'm new learning CSS just today, i can't move on, i don't know how to add a footer, like all rights reserved?
I have done below code so far, i tried inserting it before end of div tags but i can't seem to insert a footer? I'm lost please help me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

here's what i've done so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cascading Menus</title>

<!-- Internal Style -->
<style>
*
{
margin: 0px;    
}

#table
{
    font-size:100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
background: #aac6e9;
border: 3px solid red;
color:#396;

}

#spaceheader
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    background: #aac6e9;
}




.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 80%; /* adjust height of the body */
  min-width: 80%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 30px 50px 100px 50px;  /* top, right, bottom, left */
  background: #aac6e9;

}

.tab  
{
  float: left; /* this is responsible for tabs to align left */

}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px 40px; /* menu bar item height width */
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  top: -29px;
  -   webkit-transition: background-color .17s linear;
    }
    .tab [type=radio] {
      display: none;   
    }
    .content {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  -webkit-transition: opacity .6s linear;
   opacity: 0;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
   z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
   z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}





    </style>

</head>
<body> 
<h1> </h1>

<div id="table">
<div id="spaceheader">
</div>


<div class="tabs">


   <div class="tab">
   <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
   <label for="tab-1">Home</label>

   <div class="content">
       <p>Stuff for Tab One</p>
   </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">About Us</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>

           <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Gallery</label>

       <div class="content">
            <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>

               <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-4">Forum</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Four</p>

           <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-5">Sign up</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>

           <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
       </div> 

    </div>

</div> <!--*end of table tag -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is what exactly?  You don't know how to insert a tag containing your desired content?  You don't know how to style it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

**in your html code add:**

```
<div id="footer">
    &copy; All rights reserved
</div>
```

**and in your css add (UPDATE):**

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GrnYE/)

Comment: The <center> tag is deprecated and should not be used.  You also don't need position: absolute; for this.

Comment: the alignment is not centered, everytime i adjust the position and margin, it gives me this http://s16.postimg.org/84y2viql1/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.png   :(

Comment: @user2232273 The <center> tag is deprecated.  It shouldn't be used anymore and hasnt been used for a long while now.

Comment: @Michael: Ok i understand it.

Comment: You are really great! but how do you take off the unwanted space, shown being pointed by the arrow in this image: http://s10.postimg.org/hovfeujtl/0000000000000000000.png  ?

Comment: what space? the blue below the orange background? the image doesn´t show a lot

Comment: yes the blue background space ABOVE and BELOW the Orange background? it doesn't look neat :/

Comment: i define for the bottom 0px. this means the position are always at the end of the page. For the space below use bootstrap libray. you can find it here --> http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/.  With this libray automatic fixed the footer and header without margins at the end or at the top

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what you said, i'm new to CSS. I tried adjusting the margin but nothing happened, the space ABOVE the orange background is still there :/ is there any way to remove it without dislocating the design?

Comment: do you want to put the footer directly after the white content without space?is it this what you want?

Comment: yes that's right, is there any way to do it without dislocating the other design?

Comment: Yes.. After you close the last div tag for your table. Add my HTML solution and for the css style remove the position and bottom properties..add only the width text-align and background properties let me know something

Answer (score 1):

You can do with:

```
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

or HTML 5:

```
<footer>
</footer>
```

and add CSS:

```
#footer {
  something
}
```

or for HTML 5:

```
footer {
  something
}
```

For copyright simply use `&copy;` where you want the copyright symbol, ©.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of footer you want, but try this. You can modify it as much as needed.

Html:

```
  <div id="footer">
    <p>All rights reserved</p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
   #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #333333;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
 }

 #footer p {
    padding-top: 40px;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add some HTML and a little CSS to center your text.

### If using HTML5...

**HTML:**

```
<footer>
  <p>&copy; Copyright 2011. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
footer { text-align: center; }
```

---

### If using HTML4...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer">
  <p>&copy; Copyright 2011. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#footer { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: How do you handle cases where a browser doesn't support `HTML5`?

Comment: is there anyway to put it inside the table tag here's the pic of screen shot: http://s12.postimg.org/apuu00lgd/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.png